# How to use python language to extract specific data from a file

Tags: python, filter, extract

How can i write a python program to extract Date, and Cumulative Production data for Oil, Gas  and water and their respective values from a text file containing data set as shown below . Thanks

---

TIME: 3622    days                              X P T   S E C T O R   S U M M A R Y                              DATE: 2025:12:01

---

```
                                                     Reservoir
```

===================================================================================================================================

```
                           SECTOR-1   SECTOR-2   SECTOR-3                                                                       
                           MATRIX     FRACTURE   FIELD
```

Bulk Volume
   Total Bulk Volume.  M rft3  2.42995E+7 2.43E+7    4.85995E+7
 Pore Volumes
   Total Pore Volume.  M rft3  3.22463E+6 485.86     3.22511E+6
   HC. Pore Volume     M rft3  2.57897E+6 388.56     2.57935E+6
 Originally in Place
   Stock Tank Oil      M STB   0          0          0
   Adsorbed Gas       MM SCF   2.41498E+5 0          2.41498E+5
   Gas at Surface     MM SCF   7.51141E+5 76.792     7.51218E+5
   Water at Surface    M STB   1.15937E+5 17.469     1.15954E+5
 Currently in Place
   Stock Tank Oil      M STB   0          0          0
   Adsorbed Gas       MM SCF   2.37806E+5 0          2.37806E+5
   Gas at Surface     MM SCF   7.01409E+5 69.061     7.01478E+5
   Water at Surface    M STB   1.15937E+5 17.469     1.15954E+5
   Adsorbed Gas: Componentized
   CH4             MM moles    2.84948E+5 0          2.84948E+5
   Reservoir Oil       M rbbl  0          0          0
   Reservoir Free Gas  M rft3  2.57897E+6 388.56     2.57935E+6
   Reservoir Water     M rbbl  1.14997E+5 17.329     1.15014E+5
   Cum Water Influx    M STB   0          0          0
 Average Pressures
   Total PV Ave.      psia     2739.7     2707.6     2739.7
   HC PV Ave.         psia     2739.7     2707.7     2739.7
   PV Ave. Datum P    psia     2739.7     2707.6     2739.7
   HC PV Ave. Datum P psia     2739.7     2707.7     2739.7
 Average Temperature
   Bulk Vol Ave.      degF     150        150        150
 Ave. Saturations
   Oil                         0          0          0
   Gas                         0.79977    0.79975    0.79977
   Water                       0.20023    0.20025    0.20023
 Percentage Recovery 
   Stock Tank Oil              100        100        100
   Gas at Surface              6.6221     0          6.6214
   Water                       2.35982E-5 0          2.35946E-5
 Cumulative Injection 
   Solvent         MM SCF      0          0          0
   Water            M STB      0          0          0
 Cumulative Production 
   Oil              M STB      0          0          0
   Gas             MM SCF      49741      0          49741
   Water            M STB      2.7359E-2  0          2.7359E-2
   Wet Gas         MM SCF      49866      0          49866
 Injection Rate 
   Gas             MM SCF/day  0          0          0
   Water            M STB/day  0          0          0
 Production Rate 
   Oil              M STB/day  0          0          0
   Gas             MM SCF/day  12.652     0          12.652
   Water            M STB/day  1.13795E-6 0          1.13795E-6
   Wet Gas         MM SCF/day  12.684     0          12.684

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you were *supposed* to finish before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad. Do you have any code already written? Or, are you just really new to programming?

To get you started anyway:

```
with open('filname.txt') as f:
    handle = f.readlines()
    for line in handle:
        # read the header
        if end_of_header:
            break
     there_are_more_lines = True  
     while there_are_more_lines:
        try:
            line = next(handle)
            # parse the line
        except StopIteration:
            there_are_more_lines = False
```

So since I don't know your background, I quickly explain. I am opening the file with 'with'. Now I can read the file line by line with the function readlines(). I put the output of this function in 'handle'. This is now an iterator I can iterate over.
There are now two parts of the text file to go over. First the header. You should parse the header and find some condition that can tell when the header stops.
Second the body. In my example I read all the lines and catch a StopIteration (end of file) to break the while loop. You should find something to parse each line.
Usefull other functions: `string.split()`  `string.startwith('something')`

If you're really new to python, this might not been the best help, [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/) or something else might be a better place to start gathering knowledge to solve the problem.

Good luck.

EDIT:
To get and parse the last three numbers of each line you could use:

```
list(map(float, line.split()[-3:])
```

This line of code first split()s the line based on the space. Then takes the last three 'words', the numbers, and uses a map to put them all through the float function. The float function converts them all to numbers (and the float function understands the scientific notation as used in the file). The map function applies the float function to each item the list created by my split. The map function returns an iterator type. If you don't now how to work with an iterator you can directly conveniently turn it back into a list.

Comment: Thanks for the help,yes am new to programming, here is what i did myself but i could not get the values following the words input_file="filename.txt"
key_words = "Cumulative Production "   #Starting key words
stop_words = "Injection Rate" #Stopping key words, net section in your file
flag = 0 #Indicate cumulative production line has been located or not
production=[]

with open(input_file) as f:
 f = f.readlines()

for lines in f:
 if stop_words in lines:
  break
 if key_words in lines:
  flag=1
  continue
 if flag==1:
                production.append(lines)

Comment: Edited to explain a way to get the values following the words.